# Importing files from different folder, *project-wide*

Tags: python, import, python-import

There is a popular Python question called [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).

But the top answer there mentions adding stuff to "some_file.py", and that will obviously only apply to imports inside that file.

What if I want to specify an additional dir to import from, project-wide?

I don't want to modify PYTHONPATH, as I believe a per-project solution is cleaner.

I don't want to use python packages for this, because I feel they'll probably just complicate stuff. E.g. maybe I'll need to manually recompile .py files into .pyc files every time I make a change to the code in the other folder.

Comment: Dynamically alter python path at run time?

Comment: No need to *... manually recompile .py  files into .pyc files every time I make a change to the code in the other folder.*. Just use a package that is what they are for.

Comment: @MikeMüller: Ok, I just read [this tutorial](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/) and it doesn't say how another project can find a package that I've created. And [this one](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) explains how to "make trouble-free packages for community use" which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I want to specify an additional dir to import from, project-wide?

### Solution 1: Package installed in develop mode

[Create a regular package with  `setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) and install it with `-e` option:

```
python -m pip install -e /path/to/dir_with_setup_py/
```

> -e, --editable    Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
>                                 path or a VCS url.

Now, as soon as you update your code, the new version will be used at import
without reinstalling anything.

### Solution 2: Dynamically modify `sys.path`

You can add as many directories dynamically to the search path for Python packages as you want. Make this the very first lines of code you execute:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('my/path/to/my/file1')
sys.path.append('my/path/to/my/file2')
```

or to make the first to be found:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'my/path/to/my/file1')
sys.path.insert(0, 'my/path/to/my/file2')
```

Now the files:

```
my/path/to/my/file1/myscript1.py
my/path/to/my/file2/myscript2.py
```

can be imported anywhere in your project:

```
import myscript1
import myscript2
```

No need to modify `sys.path` again as long as this Python process is running.